# How to convert list field into many-to-many table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, many-to-many, pattern-matching, database-migration

I have inherited a database in which a person table has a field called authorised_areas. The front end allows the user to choose multiple entries from a pick list (populated with values from the description field of the area table) and then sets the value of authorised_areas to a comma-delimited list. I am migrating this to a MySQL database and while I'm at it, I would like to improve the database integrity by removing the authorised_areas field from the person table and create a many-to-many table person_area which would just hold pairs of person-area keys.  There are several hundred person records, so I would like to find a way to do this efficiently using a few MySQL statements, rather than individual insert or update statements.

Just to clarify, the current structure is something like:

```
person
id    name    authorised_areas
1     Joe     room12, room153, 2nd floor office
2     Anna    room12, room17

area
id    description
1     room12
2     room17
3     room153
4     2nd floor office
```

...but what I would like is:

```
person
id    name
1     Joe
2     Anna

area
id    description
1     room12
2     room17
3     room153
4     2nd floor office

person_area
person_id     area_id
1             1
1             3
1             4
2             1
2             2
```

There is no reference to the area id in the person table (and some text values in the lists are not exactly the same as the description in the area table), so this would need to be done by text or pattern matching.  Would I be better off just writing some php code to split the strings, find the matches and insert the appropriate values into the many-to-many table?

I'd be surprised if I were the first person to have to do this, but google search didn't turn up anything useful (perhaps I didn't use the appropriate search terms?) If anyone could offer some suggestions of a way to do this efficiently, I would very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

While it is possible to do this I would suggest that as a one off job it would probably be quicker to knock up a php (or your favorite scripting language) script to do it with multiple inserts.

If you must do it in a single statement then have a table of integers (0 to 9, cross join against itself to get as big a range as you need) and join this against your original table, using string functions to get the Xth comma and from that each of the values for each row.

Possible, and I have done it but mainly to show that having a delimited field is not a good idea. It would likely be FAR quicker to knock up a script with multiple inserts.

You could base an insert on something like this SELECT (although this also comes up with a blank line for each person as well as the relevant ones, and will only cope with up to 1000 authorised areas per person)

```
SELECT z.id, z.name, x.an_authorised_area
FROM person z
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
SELECT DISTINCT a.id, SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( authorised_areas, ",", b.ournumbers ) , ",", -1 ) AS an_authorised_area
FROM person a, (
SELECT hundreds.i *100 + tens.i *10 + units.i AS ournumbers
FROM integers AS hundreds
CROSS JOIN integers AS tens
CROSS JOIN integers AS units
)b
)x ON z.id = x.id
```